# How to embed an Atlassian Conflence page in another html page

Tags: html, eclipse-rcp, confluence

I want to show an Atlassian Confluence wiki page in an Eclipse RCP application. I tried using html and iframe, but it does not work with confluence ("To help protect the security of information you enter into this website, the publisher of this content does not allow it to be displayed in a frame"). Is there a workaround? I have access to the wiki and basic editing rights. If I knew what to ask for, I could maybe request some more advanced changes.

Answer (score 0):

You could use [Comala Share It](https://marketplace.atlassian.com/plugins/com.keinoby.confluence.plugins.share-attachments/server/overview) to generate a public link to the page, then use your iframe. Here is explained how https://wiki.comalatech.com/display/SI/How+to+Embed+a+Shared+Page

Disclaimer, I work in Comalatech, the company behind that commercial add-on.

Regards,
Gorka